# Transformation of vector CRS

Tags: coordinate-system, vector-layer

I have a vector file with CRS: CRS EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 - Geographic, Extent: Extent 984173.1875000000000000,980041.1875000000000000 : 997289.5000000000000000,999778.81250000000000.

It has to sit on my map with the follwing details: CRS: CRS EPSG:32740 - WGS 84 / UTM zone 40S - Projected Extent: Extent 532190.0000000000000000,7730270.0000000000000000 : 584590.0000000000000000,7795420.0000000000000000

I tried changing in the "Properties"/Source and then run Vector/Reproject

It does not work. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Which software are you working with? What do you mean with "it has to sit on my map"?

Comment: It can't be `CRS: CRS EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 - Geographic, Extent: Extent 984173.1875000000000000,980041.1875000000000000 : 997289.5000000000000000,999778.81250000000000`. EPSG:4326 is using degrees as units and  maximum extent is between -90 and +90 (lat), -180 and +180 (lon). You must find out the correct CRS of your source data.